# Change Map Type through UIButton Toggle - Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

How can I switch between the standard Map view to the Satellite Map View using a UIButton to act as a toggle? Using Google Maps iOS SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
private var mapView: GMSMapView!

mapView.mapType = .satellite
```

You can replace "satellite" with other map types.

You can make a button and give it a function, something like this:

```
private func buttonClick() {
    switch mapView.mapType {
    case .satellite:
        mapView.mapType = .normal
    default:
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    }
```